# Adding Static Image to WooCommerce Content-Single-Product template

Tags: plugins, images, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to add some static images to the single product template in WooCommerce but they are not displaying properly.

I am hooking into the `woocommerce_after_single_product_summary` hook and everything is being included in the file fine.

I have added, among other things, the following code:

```
<div class="product-detail-header">
    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory(); ?>/images/sig-technical.png" />
    <h3>Technical</h3>
    <hr>
</div>
```

For some reason the image path is inserting itself after the path of the current page which is obviously not where it should be pointing to.

It is translating to

`http://wp_project2/product/jazz/C:/wamp/www/wp_project2/wp-content/themes/Divi-child/images/sig-technical.png`

instead of

`C:/wamp/www/wp_project2/wp-content/themes/Divi-child/images/sig-technical.png`

I've been racking my brain and can't figure this one out. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `get_stylsheet_directory_uri()` instead.

Comment: That worked! Thanks a ton! I kinda feel stupid for not having tried that lol.

Comment: I've done the same thing a hundred times probably. You should post your code as an answer for others, it will help someone I'm sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many thanks to Nathan Powell for the fix.

Changing `get_stylesheet_directory()` to `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` will return the correct `URL`.

`get_stylesheet_directory()` returns the absolute server path to child or parent theme (hence my previous issue) whereas `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` returns the properly formed URI of child or parent theme.

I suppose the lesson is to pay close attention to exactly what function you're using as WordPress has many similarly named plugins.

You can check out the codex docs here:
[get_stylesheet_directory()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory) & [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri)